# Lock a Linux server local session - Linux from Scratch

Tags: linux, command-line, security

So leaving a console unlocked on a local server makes me nervous...

However, if I log out of a server session that is local, it seems that all the processes stop.

So in a non-GUI Linux-from-scratch minimalist setting, how do I effectively lock the screen? Seems like there should be an easy way native to the OS to leave processes running but log out of the session.

I'm definitely newer to the Linux server space, so am I missing something?

Comment: No, not really. These are all additional programs to add. There should be a way to lock the command line at the terminal when you are hooked up to server. Desktop has a lock screen that you can use, so why doesn't the server? I get it, emergency console use when you're having an outage, yada yada, but that's no excuse for not being able to secure your terminal when you walk away.

Answer (score 0):

I am also quite inexperienced so please do feel free to correct me :)

Your process are gone since they have their `stdout` attached to your shell session, which no longer exists after logout, generating a `SIGHUP` signal. You can keep them alive by,

- Utilities such as `screen` or `tmux`
- `nohup`, which redirects `stdout` thus prevents the signal

Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/how-to-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client